# Cocoa audio volume slider with bindings

Tags: objective-c, audio

Can anyone show me some boilerplate cocoa / objective-c code or point me to an open source project that implements an audio volume slider in Xcode / interface builder?

This is for an OS X (not iOS) project.

If it matters, I want to control an audio device that is specified by the user and may or may not be the default system output device.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the slider itself you're looking for, rather than actually the audio device control itself, this is the subject of the "First Cocoa Project".  Type "First Project" at the Organizer search.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to put a slider in a view. I'm looking for bindings compliant code to connect the slider to an arbitrary audio device. I'm googling, but i can't find the right set of keywords to find any sample code for this, though i know it must be a pretty common thing for most apps that play sound.